# Silverlight Datatemplate with converter code behind

Tags: c#, silverlight, code-behind

I have no XAML for my combobox, I would like to add a datatemplate with a value converter in the code behind and attach it to the combobox. Here is my code as of now and it is not working. It says it can not find my staticresource SelectableColorConverter

```
        this.Resources.Add("SelectableColorConverter", new SelectableColorConverter());
        string template = "<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007\"><TextBlock Text=\"{Binding}\" Foreground=\"{Binding Converter={StaticResource SelectableColorConverter}}\" /></DataTemplate>";
        DataTemplate dt = XamlReader.Load(template) as DataTemplate;
        this.ItemTemplate = dt;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. SelectableColorConverter is an IValueConverter.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Ultimatly have items in the combo box change colors based on rules in the converter. The combobox can not use comboboxitems so applying a template to each item at a time isn't an option. I believe that applying an item template is the only way to go about this but it appears that you cant attach one with a converter strictly from the codebehind.

Comment: Do different items have different colors? or is there only one color at a time applied to all items so that all items are colored uniformly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add link to static resource (SelectableColorConverter) to yours DataTemplate as:

```
string template = "<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007\"";
templete += "xmlns:local=\"clr-namespace:NamespadeName; assembly=AssemblyName\">"
template += "<DataTemplate.Resources> <local:SelectableColorConverter x:Key=\"colorConverter\"/>";
template += "</DataTemplate.Resources>";
template += "<TextBlock Text=\"{Binding}\" Foreground=\"{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=colorConverter}}\" />";
template += "</DataTemplate>";
```

**Or** add SelectableColorConverter to your resources in App.xaml:

```
<Application
x:Class="Test.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:convertor="using:Test.Converters"
xmlns:local="using:Test">

<Application.Resources>
    <convertor:SelectableColorConverter x:Key="SelectableColorConverter"/>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and than

```
string template = "<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007\">";
template += "<TextBlock Text=\"{Binding}\" Foreground=\"{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource SelectableColorConverter}}\" />";
template += "</DataTemplate>";
```